# Smooth but not convex

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, smooth-functions

In Theorem 4.2. of the following lecture
http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~cmcaram/EE381V_2012F/Lecture_4_Scribe_Notes.final.pdf

it is shown that when the objective function is smooth and not necessarily convex, by using Gradient Descent, $\nabla f(x_k)\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Can we conclude that $x_k$ also converges to a fixed point?

Comment: No, apply it to $f(x) = e^{-x}$, then $f'(x_k) \to 0$ but $x_k \to \infty$.

Comment: But by the update rule $x_{k+1}=x_k-\mu \nabla f(x_k)$, if $\nabla f(x_k)$ goes to $0$, then $x_{k+1}$ equals to $x_k$ and the sequence converges.

Comment: That is not  correct. For example, take $x_k = 1+{1 \over 2} + \cdots + {1 \over k}$, then $|x_{k+1} -x_k| \to 0$ but $x_k \to \infty$.